# Using users cookbook with Chef to login with public key but asks for password

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, sshd

I have both `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in my `~/.ssh` folder.

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.chef.io/2014/07/10/managing-users-and-ssh-keys-in-a-hybrid-world/) (it's basically the repo's README file) to add `myuser` with my `id_rsa.pub` key.

When I test using **Test Kitchen**, I try to login via ssh with `ssh mysuser@192.168.33.33` but it asks for a password.

I logged using `kitchen login` to check `/home/myuser/.ssh` and `/home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` permission, both seems to be OK, `drwx----` and `rw----` owned by `myuser` group `root` (though myuser doesnt belong to root group). And yes, my public key is in the `authorized_keys` file.

I'm runing SELinux on permissive. [Bento/centos-6.7](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/centos-6.7)

Why is it asking for a password, am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
I just read `/var/log/secure` and it said `bad ownership or modes for directory /home/web`.

The owner of `/home/web` is `web_admin` user, group `web_admin`.
The owner of `/home/web/.ssh` is `myuser` user, group `root`.

I'm attempting to SSH as `myuser`. Is that what's wrong?

Comment: 1) Post the verbose log to make sure your key is offered. 2) Check the server log (possibly with debug log level) to see why it is rejected.

Comment: @Jakuje I updated my question with log details and further info.

Comment: Paste your code please.

Comment: run `grep myuser /etc/passwd` and `ls -l /home/web/` if it is the home directory of your `myuser`.

Comment: `.ssh` should be owned by the owner of the home directory and be the user you're login as. I don't get why you're talking about /home/mysuer and /home/web here. what is myuser home directory ?